# How do I add a "+" in between each signed integer

Tags: c, formatting, integer, printf, addition

Output has to be like this (example):

```
1+2+3+4
```

What I'm getting is:

```
1+2+3+4+
```

I'm not using any function to add in the '+', I'm simply doing the following inside the loop that creates 'num':

```
printf("%d+", num);
```

How do I remove the last '+'? Is there any other sufficient way of doing it **with** printf? I've searched a bunch and only came to the conclusion of storing the numbers inside an array then printing them; using a function that removes the last character. Problem is, I'm not allowed to use array for this situation..

**EDIT:** Another way I tried is by using the '+' flag in '%d":

```
printf("%+d", num);
```

Though this seems to work better than the method I was doing, I would still need to remove the '+' at the very beginning:

```
+1+2+3+4
```

Any help would be nice!

**EDIT:** Here is the function that I have that loops:

```
int perfectNumGen(int num)
{
    int perfNumAlgo = pow(2, num - 1)*(pow(2, num) - 1);
    int factorNum = 1;

    printf("%d=", num);

    while (factorNum < num)
    {
        if (num % factorNum == 0)
            printf("%+d", factorNum); //this is where i need help

        factorNum++;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the form of your input?

Comment: each time u call the function, it seems that it wil print one equation right?

Comment: correct. the first time would have to look like 6=1+2+3 but i have 6=+1+2+3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

print one number before without "+"

```
printf("%d", num);
```

then do in a loop

```
printf("+%d", num);
```

according to ur code. this should work

```
int perfectNumGen(int num)
{
    int perfNumAlgo = pow(2, num - 1)*(pow(2, num) - 1);
    int factorNum = 1;

    printf("%d=", num);

    if (num % factorNum == 0)
        printf("%d", factorNum);
    factorNum++;

    while (factorNum < num)
    {
        if (num % factorNum == 0)
            printf("+%d", factorNum); //this is where i need help

        factorNum++;
    }
}
```

i agree this isnt the best way.. it does make the code look a bit dirty.. but the execution time doesnt get effected..

Comment: num is being generated from another function which needs the loop. so I cant put printf("%d", num); outside the loop or else the program will just keep running. i've added the function into op.

Comment: @Max: show the whole program, else it is imposible to suggest a work around.

Comment: ive added the function. the function is also being looped inside main();

Answer (score 0):

In your loop, print the line based on the iteration count. i.e:

```
int lim = 4;
for (int num = 0; num < lim; num++)
{
    if (num < lim)
    {
       printf("%d+", num);
    }
    else
    {
       printf("%d", num);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have one fancy trick for you:

You can just print `"\b "` (invisible backspace symbol and a space) after all numbers.

`\b` will move invisible cursor back by one symbol. And then space will get printed "above" last `+` and will erase it.